# Derivative functions.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

What is the form of the derivative function of the function 
$$\left(\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1} \right)^2$$
I need the steps of the solution not the final derivative.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions posted here shouldn't be phrased in language suitable for assigning homework.  If you have some specific questions about an assigned problem --- either understanding what is asked or knowing where to go from there --- you can ask those here.  Do you understand the question that you posted?  If so, specifically where did you have difficulties in answering it? $\qquad$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:
$$\left(h(z(x))\right)' = h'(z(x))\cdot g'(x)$$
$$\left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)' = \frac{f'(x)g(x) - g'(x)f(x)}{g(x)^2}$$

If you allow $h(x) = x^2$, $z(x) = f(x)/g(x),\ \ f(x) = x^2 + 1,\ \ g(x) = x^2  - 1$... what do you get?

Answer (score 0):

I try to do things mentally so I look for what seems to be to be the simplest approach.

Here I would start by decomposing the term in the square root sign (let that be called $y$) via partial fractions:

$$y = \left(\frac{x^2+1}{x^2-1} \right) = 1 + \frac {1}{x-1} - \frac{1}{x+1}$$

Then apply chain rule noting that $(y^2)' = 2y\cdot y'$

You'll very quickly get to the answer of $\displaystyle 2\left(1 + \frac {1}{x-1} - \frac{1}{x+1}\right)\left(-\frac{1}{(x-1)^2} + \frac{1}{(x+1)^2}\right)$

and all that's left is a little simplification (only if required - personally, I think that form is fine as it is and is more useful in practical computation).

Comment: And why the downvote???

Comment: Thanks to whoever that evened out the downvote with an upvote. Appreciate it.